# Импортирование класса из другого файла

Tags: python, классы, импорт

С недавних пор изучаю Python и не совсем понимаю, как работают и формируются классы. Писал систему вычисления зарплаты по книге и пытался импортировать её в другой файл.
Сама схема:

```
class Staff:
    def __init__(self, pPosition, pName, pPay):
        self.position = pPosition
        self.name = pName
        self.pay = pPay
        print("Creating Staff Object")

    def __str__(self):
        return "Position = %s, Name = %s, Pay = %d"%(self.position, self.name, self.pay)

    def calculatePay(self):
        promt = "\nEnter number of hours worked for %s: "%(self.name)
        hours = input(promt)
        promt = "Enter the hourly rate for %s: "%(self.name)
        hourlyRate = input(promt)
        self.pay = int(hours) * int(hourlyRate)
        return self.pay

    @property
    def position(self):
        print("Getter Method")
        return self.position

    @position.setter
    def position(self, value):
        if value == 'Manager' or value == 'Basic':
            self.position = value
        else:
            print("Position is invalid. No changes made.")
```

Сохранив этот класс в отдельный файл под названием "CalculatePay", я хотел импортировать его в другой файл, где задам нужные данные(pPosition, pName, pPay). Если честно, я не совсем понимаю, как правильно нужно "давать" данные для класса. Я знаю, что нужно сообщить программе нужные ей значения, но как это именно делается я не понял.
Код нового файла:

```
import CalculatePay

officeStaff1 = Staff('Basic', 'Ivan', 0)
salary = Staff.calculatePay()

print(salary)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python works\CP.py", line 4, in <module>
    salary = calculatePay()
NameError: name 'calculatePay' is not defined
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так, ну для начала, вам необходимо сделать импорт класса в новый модуль. В первых строках файла:

```
from 'название файла, в котором находится класс' import Staff
```

Далее вы сможете создать экземпляр класса, обращаясь к классу в созданном модуле, как вы это пытались сделать:

```
officeStaff1 = Staff('Basic', 'Ivan', 0)
```

Comment: Код возникшей ошибки в результате правки:

 File "D:\Python works\CalculatePay.py", line 27, in position
    self.position = value
  [Previous line repeated 993 more times]
  File "D:\Python works\CalculatePay.py", line 26, in position
    if value == 'Manager' or value == 'Basic':
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Comment: Покажите код, как вы осуществили import

Comment: `from CalculatePay import Staff

officeStaff1 = Staff('Basic', 'Ivan', 0)
salary = Staff.calculatePay()

sys.setrecursionlimit(10)

print(salary)`

Comment: Для начала, используйте созданный экземпляр класса `officeStaff1`, чтобы обращаться к функции класса. А что по поводу рекурсии, то переименуйте функции `def position()`, например в `def positions()`. И декоратор тоже `@positions.setter`

Comment: Но с декораторами я особо не знаком, поэтому за корректность не отвечаю :)

Comment: Проблема с рекурсией действительно решилась, спасибо вам большое. Но, к огромному сожалению, теперь возникает другая ошибка, связанная с 'self'
Код ошибки: 
`salary = Staff.calculatePay()
TypeError: calculatePay() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: Возможно, я не совсем понял то, что вы имеете ввиду в первом предложении комментария: "Для начала, используйте созданный экземпляр класса officeStaff1, чтобы обращаться к функции класса."
Будьте добры, объясните развёрнуто, пожалуйста.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы не совсем понимаете, что именно вы делаете. Если вы начали изучать Python недавно, то не стоит переходить к таким сложным темам, как ООП и уж тем более декораторы. Когда я сказал, чтобы вы обращались к методу посредством экземпляра класса, то имел в виду, что нужно обращаться не так: `Staff.calculatePay()`, а вот так `officeStaff1.calculatePay()`. Посмотрите скриншот: https://gyazo.com/b3388f2fa22ada88bd33c92724929f7e

Comment: Всё работает, благодарю! Учту ваши замечания. Вы и в самом деле правы на счёт того, что я понимаю далеко не всё, что делаю.

Comment: Ошибка связанная с `self` возникает потому что вы пытаетесь вызвать функцию, которую можно вызвать только из объекта (того самого self)